# Angular2: Approach to show only allowed actions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

My application contains projects, of course there are some actions (=buttons) on this project: like, share, edit and so on. As you can think not all users should be able to edit, so I don't event want to show them the buttons.

What we did so far: We return an array of actions (as string) from the server like this: `["updateLike","editProject","withdraw"]`

In the template we do the following:

```
<button *ngFor="let action of allowedActions"> {{ action }} </button>
```

Of course this will only display all the actions. How do I execute the action onclick? What's the proper syntax and should I use something like a mapper?
Maybe I'll extend the array with one dimension to make multilingual button texts.

Answer (score 1):

You ll have to bind a click event for fucntions. And it would be better not to put all the buttons in an array and use them as a single entity and apply ngIf on each button with your condition.